# creating a form to delete a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a subscriber resource (mailinglist) and want to make a unsubscribe form. I created a remove view with a form

> ```
> <%= form_for(Subscriber.new, :action => :delete) do  %>   
>  email: <%= text_field_tag :mail %>   
>  <%= submit_tag "Sign out" %> 
> <% end %>
> ```

I try to call the delete method of the controller but instead the edit action gets called.

Comment: Have you tried `:method => :delete` as opposed to `:action => :delete` as per Shreyas's answer below?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the RESTful routes to the destroy action needs an :id of the resource to be deleted and since you use Subscriber.new as a source for creating the form, it cannot create an appropriate url to post to.

You can go around this by using routes like this:

```
<% form_for(:subscriber, :url => subscriber_path("email"), :html => {:method => :delete}) do  %>
  email: <%= text_field_tag :mail %>
  <%= submit_tag "Sign out" %>
<% end %>
```

Note that you have to edit subscriber_path to your own routing but by using "email" as an identifier you make sure that no faulthy :id is being passed to the controller and you can use the email to find the correct model to destroy as I think was what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= form_for @subscriber, :method => :delete do  %>   
  email: <%= text_field_tag :mail %>   
  <%= submit_tag "Sign out" %> 
<% end %>
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: I dont have a @subscriber. The user has to sill in its email and submit. Thats why I use Subscriber.new but when I use Subscriber.new in your code it doesn't work.