# Rails: How to confirm email address entered in text box matches current user's email address?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan

I am creating a page that allows a user to delete their account/profile.  On this page, I have a text box where the user types their email address to confirm they are indeed the current user and that they want to delete their account (upon button click).

What I want to do is, when the user clicks the "Delete Account" button below the text box, I want to grab that text and compare it to the current user's email account.  If it matches, I want to delete the user's account.  If not, I want to flash an error message.

I have some of the logic figured out, and I will paste what I have below.  **Right now, if you click the 'Delete Account' button it deletes the user's account and redirects to the home page, and flashes a 'goodbye' message on the home page.**  *However, there is no comparison functionality b/t current user's email and text box entry.*  I'm not sure if I can do this in Rails or if I will have to incorporate JavaScript.  I am using Devise and Cancan.

Please be as explicit as possible, I am fairly new to Rails. **Thank you!**

Email box and button are at /settings/profile/delete, file is 'delete.html.haml'.

**The email box**

```
.field
  = label :email, 'Email Address'
  = email_field :email, 'Enter your email address', id: 'delete-email-box'
```

**The Delete Account Button (below email box)**

```
#confirm-delete-btn
  = link_to 'Delete Account', user_registration_path, method: :delete, data: 
   { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete your account? This cannot be 
   undone!' }, class: submit btn-delete'
  = link_to 'Cancel', profile_index_path, id: 'cancel-profile'
```

**profile_controller.rb**

```
def delete
  @user = current_user
  @profile = current_user.profile
end

def destroy
  @user = current_user
  @profile = current_user.profile
  if @profile.destroy
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "User deleted."
  else
    render_error_message
  end
end
```

Comment: `params` will be passed from the form and it seems you already have `current_user` implemented so just compare the `params` value to the `current_user`'s value before destruction. Although right now it does not appear you are actually submitting the form but instead using a hyperlink so I would fix that first

Comment: @engineersmnky Would you mind showing me how to fix the form and implementing your solution?  You can add as an answer if you want so I can give you credit.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looked at how to make a form to delete items and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217266/creating-a-form-to-delete-a-resource). So your form would look like this:

```
<% form_for(:user, :url => path_for_your_destroy_action(@user), :html => {:method => :delete}) do  %>
  email: <%= text_field_tag :mail %>
  <%= submit_tag "Delete" %>
<% end %>
```

Now inside your destory method you could simply check if email matches current users email and if it does that delete his account:

```
def destroy
  if current_user.email == params[:email]
    current_user.destroy
    redirect_to your_path, notice: "user deleted"
  else
    render "your_form", notice: "invalid email"
  end
end
```

Comment: nice!  i will try this now and get back to you.  thank you for taking the time to answer me!

Comment: FYI, still working on implementing this solution.  Will get back to you soon.

Comment: Everything works! I'll post my code in full later as an answer in case anyone wants to see it.  Thanks again for your assistance!

Comment: Wouldn't the param desired been nested inside `user`? (e.g. `params[:user][:email]`)

Comment: Yeah I think It should be. I just added it to show the logic :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to David's answer, based off of your code it looks like you are also trying to delete the user's profile.  It isn't explicitly described how a user is related to a profile, but based off of how you're setting up things in your current destroy action I'm assuming its through some sort of association. In this case, you will still need to destroy the profile or it will remain as an unused row in your database.  This can be accomplished through a simple addition to the destroy action:

```
def destroy
  if current_user.email == params[:email]
    current_user.profile.destroy
    current_user.destroy
    redirect_to your_path, notice: "user deleted"
  else
    render "your_form", notice: "invalid email"
  end
end
```

However, this is clunky and can easily lead to errors in the future when you need to implement similar functionality elsewhere. A much DRYer Rails way to deal with this in at the Model Layer:

**User.rb:**

```
has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
```

This will ensure that anytime a user is destroyed, its associated profile is also automatically destroyed.

Comment: thanks for the input!  yeah, i need to clean up some things.  there is a dependency already built in, so they are both destroyed using the code above.  i will post the full code soon, in case someone else runs across this scenario.